# OpenCV and Regions of Interests (ROI)?

Tags: opencv

How does OpenCV handle Regions of Interest (ROI)?

Say I set a region of interest using `cvSetImageROI()`. Is that ROI stored with the `IplImage` structure?

If so, when I pass the image to functions such as `cvSmooth()` or `cvFindContours()`, will those functions operate on the whole image or just the ROI?

`cvFindContours()` seems to provide an offset value to compensate for using ROIs [(see documentation)](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/cgi-pub/oleykin/website/OpenCVHelp/), but its not clear to me if `cvFindContours()` is aware of the ROI or if one provides the ROI manually.

I am using OpenCV 1.1 with Intel's performance primitives installed.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ROI is stored within the [IplImage structure](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/basic_structures.html#iplimage), most functions in the [documentation](http://cdn.bitbucket.org/rsb/opencv-documentation/downloads/OpenCVDocumentation.pdf) will adhere to any ROI and only perform their operation on that region.

Answer (score 1):

The ROI is stored in the IplImage structure. And every function adheres to the ROI. If you find a function that works on the pixels beyond the ROI, you can report it as a bug.

Also, you do not have ROI in matrices.